# "…/auto/List/Util/Util.so: undefined symbol: PL_stack_sp at …/XSLoader.pm" only when running test suite with CGI::Test _and_ on Travis CI

Tags: perl, cgi, travis-ci, perlbrew, xs

I have a Perl module called [CGI::Github::Webhook](https://github.com/xtaran/CGI-Github-Webhook) whose test suite [works fine on Travis CI so far on the branch master](https://travis-ci.org/xtaran/CGI-Github-Webhook/branches). But since it's a module for writing CGI scripts, I wanted to test it with [CGI::Test](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Test) as this would be closer to real-life scenarios.

But [every Travis CI run in the branch `cgi-test` failed so far](https://travis-ci.org/xtaran/CGI-Github-Webhook/branches). Except for the runs with Perl 5.24 and above, every failed run contained these lines, just with different Perl version numbers in the paths:

```
Attempt to reload List/Util.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/Sub/Exporter/Progressive.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/Sub/Exporter/Progressive.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/Devel/GlobalDestruction.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/Devel/GlobalDestruction.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/Moo/_Utils.pm line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/Moo/_Utils.pm line 21.
Compilation failed in require at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/Moo.pm line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/Moo.pm line 4.
Compilation failed in require at /home/travis/build/xtaran/CGI-Github-Webhook/build_dir/lib/CGI/Github/Webhook.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/travis/build/xtaran/CGI-Github-Webhook/build_dir/lib/CGI/Github/Webhook.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at ./cgitest.pl line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./cgitest.pl line 10.
script /cgi-bin/cgitest.pl generated no valid headers at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/CGI/Test.pm line 468.
Use of uninitialized value $in_fname in unlink at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/CGI/Test.pm line 469.
Use of uninitialized value $in_fname in concatenation (.) or string at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/CGI/Test.pm line 469.
can't unlink : No such file or directory at /home/travis/perl5/perlbrew/perls/5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/CGI/Test.pm line 469.
```

Example taken from [currently latest run under Perl 5.22](https://travis-ci.org/xtaran/CGI-Github-Webhook/jobs/133666035#L311). The symptoms on Perl 5.24 are more or less the same, just the initial error message seems differently phrased.

Anyone an idea what's going wrong here?  Do I even have a chance to fix this? Looks like a bug to me. But in which module? I've found no matching bug reports [against CGI-Test](https://github.com/nohuhu/CGI-Test/issues), [Scalar-List-Utils](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Scalar-List-Utils) or [XSLoader](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Search/Results.html?Query=Queue=%27perl5%27%20AND%20Content%20LIKE%20%27module=XSLoader%27%20AND%20%28Status=%27open%27%20OR%20Status=%27new%27%20OR%20Status=%27stalled%27%29), but would have expected that such an issue is already reported since it doesn't seem to be new. (First noticed several months ago.)

It though does not fail if I run that test suite with the system-provided Perl and Perl Modules on Debian Unstable (currently Perl version 5.22), so I can't really reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: I tried to clone the branch `cgi-test` to my Ubuntu laptop and then run `dzil run prove` to check for failed tests. The first run failed due to missing modules: File::Slurper, Test::File, and CGI::Test. After installing these three modules, all tests passed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I usually use `dzil smoke` or `dzil test` instead of `dzil run prove`. Not sure if that makes any difference here. Dist::Zilla should gather all required modules and write them into `META.yml` and `META.json`. And since the error message is clearly not a "missing module" issue, I doubt that the issues you ran into are related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it myself: It were the `#!/usr/bin/perl` shebang lines in my example CGI scripts in the test suite (and/or maybe also the same shebang line in `t/cgi-test.t`).

[Changing them to `#!/usr/bin/env perl` fixed the issue](https://travis-ci.org/xtaran/CGI-Github-Webhook/builds/133749890), i.e. the tested CGI scripts were running with the system `perl` instead of the perlbrew-installed one.