# Smoke tests fail for most CPANTesters, but work fine on Travis CI and locally under perlbrew-built Perl

Tags: perl, automated-tests, cpan, perlbrew

This is very similar to [my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505516/auto-list-util-util-so-undefined-symbol-pl-stack-sp-at-xsloader-pm-only/37512321) except that this time, the smoke tests of [CGI::Github::Webhook](https://github.com/xtaran/CGI-Github-Webhook) are [fine on Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/xtaran/CGI-Github-Webhook) as well as locally (both, with the OS installed Perl 5.22 and with a Perl 5.24 built and installed via Perlbrew, see below), but [fail in all but one CPAN Testers report](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=CGI-Github-Webhook+0.04).

The most common error there looks like this:

```
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/bbbike/perl-5.24.0/bin/perl5.24.0" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/auth-fail.t ............ ok
t/author-critic.t ........ skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/author-pod-coverage.t .. skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/author-pod-syntax.t .... skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/basic-functionality.t .. ok
Attempt to reload List/Util.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /bbbike/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/Sub/Exporter/Progressive.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /bbbike/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/Sub/Exporter/Progressive.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /bbbike/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/Devel/GlobalDestruction.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /bbbike/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/Devel/GlobalDestruction.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /bbbike/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/Moo/_Utils.pm line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /bbbike/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/Moo/_Utils.pm line 26.
Compilation failed in require at /bbbike/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/Moo.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /bbbike/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/Moo.pm line 12.
Compilation failed in require at /tmpfs/.cpan-build-cpansand/2016060903/CGI-Github-Webhook-0.04-pS8kOL/blib/lib/CGI/Github/Webhook.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /tmpfs/.cpan-build-cpansand/2016060903/CGI-Github-Webhook-0.04-pS8kOL/blib/lib/CGI/Github/Webhook.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at ./cgitest.pl line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./cgitest.pl line 10.
script /cgi-bin/cgitest.pl generated no valid headers at /opt/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/CGI/Test.pm line 468.
Use of uninitialized value $in_fname in unlink at /opt/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/CGI/Test.pm line 469.
Use of uninitialized value $in_fname in concatenation (.) or string at /opt/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/CGI/Test.pm line 469.
can't unlink : No such file or directory at /opt/perl-5.24.0/lib/site_perl/5.24.0/CGI/Test.pm line 469.
```

Locally with my perlbrew-built Perl 5.24 it looks like this:

```
[…]-Github-Webhook-0.04 → perlbrew use 5.24.0
[…]-Github-Webhook-0.04 → which perl
/home/abe/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/bin/perl
[…]-Github-Webhook-0.04 → perl -v

This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 0 (v5.24.0) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2016, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied […]
[…]-Github-Webhook-0.04 → perl Makefile.PL
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for CGI::Github::Webhook
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
[…]-Github-Webhook-0.04 → prove -l
t/auth-fail.t ............ ok   
t/author-critic.t ........ skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/author-pod-coverage.t .. skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/author-pod-syntax.t .... skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/basic-functionality.t .. ok     
t/cgi-test-auth-fail.t ... ok   
t/cgi-test.t ............. ok   
t/methods-non-json.t ..... ok    
t/methods.t .............. ok    
t/release-kwalitee.t ..... skipped: these tests are for release candidate testing
 All tests successful.
 Files=10, Tests=52,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.00 sys +  0.66 cusr  0.07 csys =  0.77 CPU)
 Result: PASS
```

Even if I call it the very same way as done in the CPAN Testers report, it does not fail for me:

```
[…]-Github-Webhook-0.04 → PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /home/abe/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.0/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/auth-fail.t ............ ok   
t/author-critic.t ........ skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/author-pod-coverage.t .. skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/author-pod-syntax.t .... skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/basic-functionality.t .. ok     
t/cgi-test-auth-fail.t ... ok   
t/cgi-test.t ............. ok   
t/methods-non-json.t ..... ok    
t/methods.t .............. ok    
t/release-kwalitee.t ..... skipped: these tests are for release candidate testing
All tests successful.
Files=10, Tests=52,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.02 sys +  0.68 cusr  0.05 csys =  0.77 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

But I fail to see why I can't reproduce those errors despite nearly every CPAN Testers report fails for the 0.04 version.

Comment: Do you know which version of each prerequisite module was used by the testers?

Comment: @melpomene: Possibly visible in the reports. At least I remember having found (and fixed) issues when Moo < 2 was used that way.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting a different mix of libraries with perlbrew than with a vanilla cpan install.  From your error messages, it looks like a few dependencies are missing.

I tried installing through cpan on perl (5.20.1), the tests seem to fail due to a warning getting inserted into the cgi output by Path::Tiny

```
cpan CGI::Github::Webhook

... skipping dependencies ...

CGI::Test is up to date (1.111).
  ABE/CGI-Github-Webhook-0.04.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /home/felix/.cpan/build/CGI-Github-Webhook-0.04-10wq5g
  ABE/CGI-Github-Webhook-0.04.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for A/AB/ABE/CGI-Github-Webhook-0.04.tar.gz
cp static-badges/errored.png blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/errored.png
cp static-badges/failed.svg blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/failed.svg
cp static-badges/failed.png blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/failed.png
cp static-badges/success.svg blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/success.svg
cp static-badges/errored.svg blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/errored.svg
cp static-badges/success.png blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/success.png
cp lib/CGI/Github/Webhook.pm blib/lib/CGI/Github/Webhook.pm
Manifying 1 pod document
  ABE/CGI-Github-Webhook-0.04.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
Skip blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/success.png (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/errored.svg (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/failed.svg (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/errored.png (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/failed.png (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/auto/share/module/CGI-Github-Webhook/success.svg (unchanged)
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/auth-fail.t ............ 1/3 
#   Failed test 'CGI output as expected'
#   at t/auth-fail.t line 28.
#          got: 'Unrecognized option(s) passed to make_path(): err at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Path/Tiny.pm line 1117.
# Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
# 
# Authentication failed
# '
#     expected: 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
# 
# Authentication failed
# '
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 3.
t/auth-fail.t ............ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/3 subtests 
t/author-critic.t ........ skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/author-pod-coverage.t .. skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/author-pod-syntax.t .... skipped: these tests are for testing by the author
t/basic-functionality.t .. 1/12 
#   Failed test 'CGI output as expected'
#   at t/basic-functionality.t line 33.
#          got: 'Unrecognized option(s) passed to make_path(): err at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Path/Tiny.pm line 1117.
# Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
# 
# Successfully triggered
# '
#     expected: 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
# 
# Successfully triggered
# '

#   Failed test 'CGI output as expected'
#   at t/basic-functionality.t line 65.
#          got: 'Unrecognized option(s) passed to make_path(): err at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Path/Tiny.pm line 1117.
# Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
# 
# Trigger failed
# '
#     expected: 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
# 
# Trigger failed
# '
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 12.
t/basic-functionality.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200) Failed 2/12 subtests

t/cgi-test-auth-fail.t ... ok   
t/cgi-test.t ............. ok   
t/methods-non-json.t ..... Unrecognized option(s) passed to make_path(): err at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Path/Tiny.pm line 1117.
t/methods-non-json.t ..... ok    
t/methods.t .............. Unrecognized option(s) passed to make_path(): err at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Path/Tiny.pm line 1117.
t/methods.t .............. ok    
t/release-kwalitee.t ..... skipped: these tests are for release candidate testing

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/auth-fail.t          (Wstat: 256 Tests: 3 Failed: 1)
   Failed test:  2
   Non-zero exit status: 1
t/basic-functionality.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 12 Failed: 2)
   Failed tests:  2, 8
   Non-zero exit status: 2
Files=10, Tests=52,  3 wallclock secs ( 0.10 usr  0.02 sys +  2.41 cusr  0.25 csys =  2.78 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/10 test programs. 3/52 subtests failed.
Makefile:878: recipe for target 'test_dynamic' failed
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  ABE/CGI-Github-Webhook-0.04.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
   reports ABE/CGI-Github-Webhook-0.04.tar.gz
```

Here is a stacktrace for that warning:

```
cpan look CGI::Github::Webhook

/.cpan/build/CGI-Github-Webhook-0.04-wA0tww/t $ perl -d -I../lib cgi/basic.pl 'echo foo'

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.44
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

Unrecognized option(s) passed to make_path(): err at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Path/Tiny.pm line 1117.
 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/File/Path.pm line 115.
    File::Path::mkpath("/tmp/XtmjrOLDl8/auto/share/module") called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Path/Tiny.pm line 1117
    Path::Tiny::mkpath(Path::Tiny=ARRAY(0xa6e67cc)) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Test/File/ShareDir/TempDirObject.pm line 75
    Test::File::ShareDir::TempDirObject::_module_tempdir(Test::File::ShareDir::TempDirObject=HASH(0xa5b316c)) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Test/File/ShareDir/TempDirObject.pm line 112
    Test::File::ShareDir::TempDirObject::_module_share_target_dir(Test::File::ShareDir::TempDirObject=HASH(0xa5b316c), "CGI::Github::Webhook") called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Test/File/ShareDir/TempDirObject.pm line 132
    Test::File::ShareDir::TempDirObject::_install_module(Test::File::ShareDir::TempDirObject=HASH(0xa5b316c), "CGI::Github::Webhook") called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.1/Test/File/ShareDir.pm line 60
    Test::File::ShareDir::import("Test::File::ShareDir", "-share", HASH(0xa416f90)) called at cgi/basic.pl line 9
    main::BEGIN() called at cgi/basic.pl line 13
    eval {...} called at cgi/basic.pl line 13
main::(cgi/basic.pl:16):    my $cgi = CGI->new();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm quite sure that the issues you ran into are different ones, but ones I should take into account anyways. If there are missing dependencies, it could be an issue of `Dist::Zilla::Plugin::AutoPrereqs`. Will have a closer look at your findings later, thanks!